# admob Web Integration (iPhone & Android)

Tags: admob

http://developer.admob.com/wiki/Android#AdMob_Android_SDK
There they have an example of the simplest smartphone web integration

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var admob_vars = {
 pubid: '[PUBLISHER_ID]', // publisher id
 bgcolor: '000000', // background color (hex)
 text: 'FFFFFF', // font-color (hex)
 test: true // test mode, set to false if non-test mode
};
</script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://mm.admob.com/static/iphone/iadmob.js">
</script>
```

Turns out that if I put that in an html file with my publisher ID, upload to the Dropbox Public folder and access it with my phone.. nothing is shown and admob says my site is inactive (never received an ad request).

It seems like everybody except me is not having issues with this.. So, anybody knows what's wrong?

Comment: I'm also have the same issue! Also what I found, is that this iadmob.js script just dont' make any requests to server. But I've opened it under desktop. I just cant' understand, why do we need this "test" mode if it just dont' work at all?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

AdMob Smartphone Web is not supported any more

> Please note that we are closing down AdMob Smartphone Web on May 1, 2012 and consolidating it with the main Google AdSense for content product. If you would like to monetize a mobile website, we strongly encourage you to either sign up for or log in to your AdSense account at http://adsense.google.com. From there, you can generate the right ad tag for your mobile site.